# ASP.net Web Forms Application login using external DB

Tags: asp.net, database, authentication, webforms

I'am creating a dynamic web form aplication. It stores the users data in another database (external server) 
I know that there is aspnet_regsql.exe but i have no idea how to implement it on external server.
(i also can't loose data from existing database)
How can i force default login system to check if my database have valid credentials in my Password and UserName columns ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Membership using aspnet_regsql.exe has been obsoleted.

There are new ones -

1. [Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)
2. [Simple Membership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)
3. [ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx)

[Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) will be the closest if you want to use the legacy Membership.

> It stores the users data in another database (external server) I know
>   that there is aspnet_regsql.exe but i have no idea how to implement it
>   on external server.

Yes, you can store the Membership's tables in another database. If so, you will need to have separate connection string for the Membership.

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
  <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnection" ... />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" 
  defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
  <clear/>
  <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnection" ... />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for comprehensive answer. I afraid that i do not explain well goal that i want to achieve. Thing is that i have to authorize users which are authenticate by user login and password (that i store in external DB) I can achive that in any possible way. After a day of looking for answers and learning ASP.NET (i'm new in this technology) i figure out that maybe easier will be to override Login.Authenticate Event like here:[link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.ASPX

Comment: What do you think ? does it make any sense ?

Comment: ***I suggest you to use Membership Provider.*** If you do not use Membership Provider and just use Login.Authenticate to authenticate a user, you will need to 1) create Authentication Ticket by yourself, 2) create IPricipal object by yourself on each request. It is a lot of works if you are new to FormAuthentication.